# Retrieve value Json field

Tags: java, json

I know that we have a lot of document on that but in my case I can't apply it.. I have a JSON file like that :

```
{
    "Status": {
        "Code": 0,
        "Message": "Search OK"
    },
    "Applications": {
        "Application": [{
            "Id": 123,
            "Name": "Bob"
        },
        ...
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the value of the field "Name".

My code :

```
String jsonData = readFile("test.json");
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONObject jobj2 = (JSONObject) jobj.get("Applications");
JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(jobj2.getJSONArray("Application").toString());
```

After that I don't know what to do.. How can I resolve my problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON.

Comment: `JSONArray jarr = jobj2.getJSONArray("Application");`

Comment: @MarounMaroun I know but I should work with that

Comment: If the JSON is not valid, it wont work. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Sorry it's a valid JSON I test it in a validator online

Comment: what you have shown to us is invalid put curly braces at outer edges and comma.

Comment: Well, the JSON you posted here isn't - make sure the example in your question is correct, otherwise people are going to get confused. Also, post the error that you get when you try to run your code.

Comment: @JackO It is **not** valid, JSON must begin with "{" or "[".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this json:

```
{
"Status": {
    "Code": 0,
    "Message": "Search OK"
},
"Applications": {
    "Application": [{
        "Id": 123,
        "Name": "Bob"
    }]
}
```

}

Your code can looks like:

```
 jsonObject
    .getJSONObject("Applications")
    .getJSONArray("Application")
    .getJSONObject(0)
    .getString("Name")
```